# Moving row from bottom to the top of dataframe in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
      count  capacity  load  throughput 
Obj1  14       34       NaN     NaN

Obj2  42       NaN       30      51

Obj3  34       NaN       20      15

Obj4  23       44        NaN     NaN

0     25       20        Nan     40
```

And now I need to put the last row above the columns names.

```
       0     25       20       Nan     40
            count  capacity   load  throughput 
    Obj1     14       34       NaN     NaN

    Obj2     42       NaN       30      51

    Obj3     34       NaN       20      15

    Obj4     23       44       NaN     NaN
```

That null left-top can stay, but it's not necessary. 
Is it even possible?

Comment: Not a full answer, but I wanted to leave this here: For some situations, these kind of slicing/dicing operations can be solved with something like: `df2 = pd.concat([df2.ix[-1:], df2.ix[:-1]], axis=0)`, for the case when the last row needs to be sitting on top.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting last row and also for removing:

```
df.columns = [df.iloc[-1],df.columns]
df = df.iloc[:-1]
#if need remove columns names
df.columns.names = (None, None)
print (df)
        25     20.0  Nan       40.0
     count capacity load throughput
Obj1    14     34.0  NaN        NaN
Obj2    42      NaN   30       51.0
Obj3    34      NaN   20       15.0
Obj4    23     44.0  NaN        NaN
```

Comment: I need that row above the columns.
I do this with appending two dataframes, that's not a problem, but thank you.

Comment: It works, but take Obj4, not the last row which have not a nema of row, there is 0, maybe that's index?

Comment: it seems yes, you can remove it by `df.index.name = None`